# How to import fs on the server side

Tags: node.js, next.js

I'm trying to send an **ssr** page containing the contents of a txt file, however I'm stuck on the part of being able to import the fs.

I understand that I need to be on the server side to be able to import the fs, I tried to use this code, without success

```js
// pages/index.js

import fs from 'fs'

export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
    return {
        props: {}
    }
}

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <h1>...</h1>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `import()` or `require()` syntax inside `getServerProps`.

```js
// pages/index.js
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  const fs = await import('fs');
  // or
  const fs = require('fs');

  return {
    props: {},
  };
}

export default function Home() {
  return <h1>...</h1>;
}
```